# C#: Catching an exceptions throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-1.4

I have the following code

```
try 
{
    naughtyMethod();
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error" + e.Message);
    // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error" + e.ToString()); // causes an exception
    // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error" + e.StackTrace); // causes an exception
}
```

The second two lines throw an exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

It is a Xamarin application with .Net standard 1.4.

Any way around this? I need to log the stack trace.

Funny enough, if I add a break point before, I am able to view `e.StackTrace` in my debugger.

Comment: Your catch argument is **ex**, but you are calling methods on the **e** object? Or is that just a typo here?

Comment: it is a typo :)

Comment: Possible cause: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18845